# How count date between date today and jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-plugins

I need get number  years between today data and data datepicker. My count function does not work.
Jquery datepicker

```
var datepicker = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            closeText: "Đóng",
            prevText: "Trước",
            nextText: "Sau",
            currentText: "Hôm nay",
            monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
            dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
            dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
            dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
            weekHeader: "Tuần",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", dateText);
                console.log(dt);
                flatpickr = dt.getFullYear();
                console.log("Birth Year: " + flatpickr);
               
            }  
        }).attr('readOnly', 'true');
```

Function date today

```
  function GetTodayDate() {
            let tdate = new Date();
            let yyyy = tdate.getFullYear();
            let currentDate = yyyy;
            return currentDate;
        };
```

Function for cout

```
  function countGetData() {
        let countGetTodayDate = GetTodayDate();
        let countGetBirthDate = GetBirthDate();
        let count = countGetTodayDate - countGetBirthDate;
        return count;
    };
```

Function for get date from datepicker. How I can do this function for my count function work. Coz after I will display number between in span

```
function GetBirthDate() {
??????????
}
```

When I use flatpickr function

```
function GetBirthDate() {
    var flatpickr = document.getElementById("flatpickr2").value;
    let tdate = new Date(flatpickr);
    let yyyy = tdate.getFullYear();
    let currentDate = yyyy;
    return currentDate;
};
```

Now I don not understand how do fuction GetBirthDay from datepicker jquery

Comment: How do you want to handle the month/day? Let's say someones birthday is `2002-12-31` and today is `2022-01-01` How old is that for you? 20 years (because `2022 - 2002 === 20`) or 19 years and 1 day?

Comment: Yes I understand what do you mean. But for me in this situation important only years. Means get years on today, and get years from chose from datepicker. Month and days not count. For display and counting next formula important only years between ... Coz example for me will important get let years = 20. Means from today I get only years. From datepicker get only years.

Comment: I add function GetBirthday how I use from flatpickr.

Comment: are you using both flatpickr and jquery datepicker at the same time?

Comment: no. it is for example.

Comment: flatpickr has disgasting vietnamese localisation. so chose datepicker.

Comment: I just can not understand how use year from datepicker inside function.

Comment: I even can not use this  inside function let flatpickr = document.getElementById("datepicker").value; coz from input I get nothing even if I select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#sample").datepicker({
  closeText: "Đóng",
  prevText: "Trước",
  nextText: "Sau",
  currentText: "Hôm nay",
  monthNames: ["Tháng một", "Tháng hai", "Tháng ba", "Tháng tư", "Tháng năm", "Tháng sáu", "Tháng bảy", "Tháng tám", "Tháng chín", "Tháng mười", "Tháng mười một", "Tháng mười hai"],
  monthNamesShort: ["Một", "Hai", "Ba", "Bốn", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy", "Tám", "Chín", "Mười", "Mười một", "Mười hai"],
  dayNames: ["Chủ nhật", "Thứ hai", "Thứ ba", "Thứ tư", "Thứ năm", "Thứ sáu", "Thứ bảy"],
  dayNamesShort: ["CN", "Hai", "Ba", "Tư", "Năm", "Sáu", "Bảy"],
  dayNamesMin: ["CN", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7"],
  weekHeader: "Tuần",
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  firstDay: 1,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: false,
  changeYear: true,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", dateText);
    console.log(dt);
    flatpickr = dt.getFullYear();
    console.log("Birth Year: " + flatpickr);
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    console.log('currentYear', year);
    var diff = year - flatpickr;
    console.log('diff', diff);
  }
}).attr('readOnly', 'true');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="sample" />
```

So this is working now.

Comment: Thank you so much... I display result... All how I want. I fight with it  2 days.

Comment: It was a pleasure to helping you.